# How to create a pdf file containing text and inline images from edit text in android studio

Tags: java, android, html, android-edittext, imageview

I am creating a simple editor in which the user can perform the basic functionalities of a text editor.
I was able to put the image in edit text with image span but the problem is to store all the data of the edit text in a pdf file. Whenever I save the pdf file it only contains the text.
Can somebody guide me on this matter?
I am placing image in edit text with following code.

```
private void setImage() {
        Drawable drawable = insertImage.getDrawable();
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);

        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append(text.getText());

// this is a string that will let you find a place, where the ImageSpan is.
        String imgId = "[img=1]";

        int selStart = text.getSelectionStart();

// current selection is replaceв with imageId
        builder.replace(text.getSelectionStart(), text.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);

        builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart + imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setText(builder);
    }
```